# Why is functional programming good?

Tags: functional-programming

I've noticed that there are certain core concepts that a lot of functional programming fanatics cling to:

- Avoiding state
- Avoiding mutable data
- Minimizing side effects
- etc...

I'm not just wondering what other things make functional programming, but why these core ideas are good? Why is it good to avoid state, and the rest?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple answer is that if you don't have extra state to worry about, your code is simpler to reason about. Simpler code is easier to maintain. You don't need to worry about things outside a particular piece of code (like a function) to modify it. This has really useful ramifications for things like testing. If your code does not depend on some state, it becomes much easier to create automated tests for that code, since you do not need to worry about initializing some state.

Having stateless code makes it simpler to create threaded programs as well, since you don't need to worry about two threads of execution modifying/reading a shared piece of data at the same time. Your threads can run independent code, and this can save loads of development time.

Essentially, avoiding state creates simpler programs. In a way, there's less "moving parts" (i.e., ways lines of code can interact), so this will generally mean that the code is more reliable and contains less faults. Basically, the simpler the code, the less can go wrong. To me this is the essence of writing state-less code.

There are plenty of other reasons to create stateless, "functional" code, but they all boil down to simplicity for me.

Comment: Should probably mention concurrency is easier to do correctly?

Comment: +1. Well said, Oleksi.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @Oleksi said, there is another important thing: referential transparency and transactional data structures. Of course, you do not need a functional programming language to do so, but it's a bit easier with them.

[Purely functional data structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) are guaranteed to remain the same - if one function returned a tree, it will always be the same tree, and all the further transforms would create new copies of it. It's much easier to backtrack to any previous version of a data structure this way, which is important for many essential algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

Very generally, functional programming means:

- encouraging the use of (first-class) functions
- discouraging the use of (mutable) state

Why is mutation a problem? Think about it: mutation is to data structures what goto is to control flow. I.e., it allows you to arbitrarily "jump" to something completely different in a rather unstructured manner. Consequently, it is occasionally useful, but most of the time rather harmful to readability, testability, and compositionality.

Comment: +1 for comparing mutable state with goto!

Answer (score 2):

One typical functional feature is "no subtyping". While it sounds a little bit odd to call this a feature, it is, for two (somehow related) reasons:

- Subtyping relationships lead to a bunch of not-so-obvious problems. If you don't limit yourself to single or mixin inheritance, you end up with the diamond problem. More important is that you have to deal with variance (covariance, contravariance, invariance), which quickly becomes a nightmare, especially for type parameters (a.k.a. generics). There are several more reasons, and even in OO languages you hear statements like "prefer composition over inheritance".
- On the other hand, if you simply leave out subtyping, you can reason much more detailled about your type system, which leads to the possibility to have (almost) full type inference, usually implemented using extensions of Hindley Milner type inference.

Of course sometimes you'll miss subtyping, but languages like Haskell have found a good answer to that problem: Type classes, which allow to define a kind of common "interface" (or "set of common operations") for several otherwise unrelated types. The difference to OO languages is that type classes can be defined "afterwards", without touching the original type definitions. It turns out that you can do almost everything with type classes that you can do with subtyping, but in a much more flexible way (and without preventing type inference). That's why other languages start to employ similar mechnisms (e.g. implicit conversions in Scala or extension methods in C# and Java 8)