# erlang - receive loop pattern matching issue

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I am trying to learn erlang. Here's a basic server which calculates area of square. It is a modified version of example 6 of the [erlang white paper](http://www1.erlang.org/white_paper.html)

Here is the code:

```
-module(area_server).
-export([start/0, loop/0]).

start() ->
    spawn(area_server, loop, []).

loop() ->
    receive
        {Client, {square, X}} ->
            Client ! X*X,
            loop()
    end.
```

The problem I have is that it seems I can bind X to only one value. Binding to any other value does not work. To test, I have the following code:

```
Server = area_server:start().

%Works and returns 100
Server ! {self(), {square, 10}}, receive Area -> Area end.

%Does not work and just does not return at all
Server ! {self(), {square, 5}}, receive Area -> Area end.
```

So how can I calculate square of 5?

Comment: Ok. So it seems the problem is not in the server but in the client code. since I receive into a variable called `Area` and it is bound to 100 once, after that it cannot be bound to 25. So if I change to `Area1` in the second call, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that on the second run `Area` is already bounded.

When you do:

```
recieve Area -> Area end.
```

The first `Area` receives the value, and the second `Area` bounds the value to the variable (`Area`). So after the first call `Area` is bounded with the value `100`.
As you might already know, Erlang is a single assigment language. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255632/the-purpose-of-single-assignment) and [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#invariable-variables) for more information.

When you are running this on the second time with the same `Area` variable, it waits on the `receive` call because there is no matching. The value you send is `25` but the `Area` inside the receive is already bounded to `100`, so there is no match. That is the reason it just hangs there.

If you want this to work, you can create a function for example:

```
get_area(Server, Amount) ->
    Server ! {self(), {square, Amount}}, receive Area -> Area end.
```

And then in the client just call `get_area(Server, 10)` or `get_area(Server, 5)`.