# How to reassign value to string variables in Erlang?

Tags: string, erlang

I am new to Erlang. I just want to reassign a value to a string variable:

```
get_alert_body(Packet) ->
    BodyElement = element(8,Packet),
    Body = "my text",
    Els = xmpp:get_els(Packet),
    lists:foreach(fun(El) ->
        ElementName = io_lib:format("~s",[xmpp:get_name(El)]),
        IsFile = string:equal(ElementName,"fileType"),
        if
            IsFile ->
                FileType = fxml:get_tag_cdata(El),
                IsPhoto = string:equal(FileType,"photo"),
                IsVideo = string:equal(FileType,"video"),
                if
                    IsPhoto ->
                        %% if it gets to this I would like to return "my photo"
                        Body = "my photo";
                    IsVideo ->
                        %% else if it gets to this I would like to return "my video"
                        Body = "my video";
                    true ->
                        %% otherwise I would like to return "my text"
                        ok
                end;
            true ->
                ok
        end
    end, Els),
    Body.
```

But I get this error:

```
error,{badmatch,"test2"}
```

Even if I do somthing like:

```
A = "test1",
A = "test2",
```

I get the same error.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.  Erlang has a feature called "single assignment", meaning that you can't change the value of a variable after assigning it for the first time.  If you try to do that, it becomes a pattern match instead, and you get a `badmatch` error just like if you try to do `"test1" = "test2"`.

Your example can be written as:

```
A =
  if
      Condition ->
          "test2";
      true ->
          "test1"
  end
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11255632/113848) and its answers for more about single assignment.

---

In your expanded example, what you're trying to do can be achieved with a fold.  That is, given a list and an additional value called an "accumulator", go through the list and call a function for each element, and let the return value of that function be the new accumulator - and return the accumulator in the end.

Use `lists:foldl/3` for that, like this:

```
get_alert_body(Packet) ->
    BodyElement = element(8,Packet),
    DefaultBody = "my text",
    Els = xmpp:get_els(Packet),
    lists:foldl(fun(El, Body) ->
        ElementName = io_lib:format("~s",[xmpp:get_name(El)]),
        IsFile = string:equal(ElementName,"fileType"),
        if
            IsFile ->
                FileType = fxml:get_tag_cdata(El),
                IsPhoto = string:equal(FileType,"photo"),
                IsVideo = string:equal(FileType,"video"),
                if
                    IsPhoto ->
                        %% if it gets to this I would like to return "my photo"
                        "my photo";
                    IsVideo ->
                        %% else if it gets to this I would like to return "my video"
                        "my video";
                    true ->
                        %% otherwise return the existing value
                        Body
                end;
            true ->
                ok
        end
    end, DefaultBody, Els).
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will edit my sample code.. Since I am confused how to use it with a loop.

Comment: I really appreciate it.. I ended up using a different solution but your response helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is not an assignment operator in erlang, rather it's a ***pattern match*** operator.

If you write:

```
{A, hello} = {10, hello}.
```

and `A` has not been *bound to* (or you can say *assigned*) a value yet, then erlang attempts to create a match for the right hand side (because `=` is the match operator).  To create a match for the right hand side, erlang binds/assigns A the value 10 (for fun you can assume that `*&*` is the assignment operator in erlang, so erlang does `A *&* 10` to assign 10 to the variable A).

It works the same way if you write:

```
B = 10,
```

In order for erlang to create a match for the right hand side, erlang assigns `B` the value `10`:  `B *&* 10`, and the match succeeds, so execution continues on the next line.  However, if you write:

```
C = 3,
C = 22,
```

then in the first line, erlang assigns the value `3` to `C`: `C *&* 3` to find a match for the right hand side (because `=` is the match operator).  But the second line is equivalent to:

```
3 = 22,
```

And the error message will say that the match operator `=` failed because there is no possible way to make the left hand side match the right hand side `22`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Erlang can't be reassigned, but they can be ["shadowed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) to achieve a similar effect. In this example, the variable `X` is "redefined" as `X ++ Y` within the scope of an anonymous function:

```
-module(main).
-export([main/1]).

main([_]) ->
    X = "X",
    Y = "Y",
    fun(X) -> io:fwrite(X) end(X++Y),
    init:stop().
```

This program prints `XY` instead of `X`, since `X` is the name of the anonymous function's parameter.