# Why can I not rewrite in a list in Erlang?

Tags: list, exception, error-handling, erlang, self-modifying

I have a list `L = [1,2,3].`

I perform the following on L:

```
lists:sublist(L,2) ++ [10] ++ lists:nthtail(3,L).
```

Instead of storing the result in a new list, I want to store the result in L itself. However, when I do so, I am getting the obvious error: `** exception error: no match of right hand side value [1,2,300]`

I don't want to use a new variable, I want to rewrite in L itself. Is it possible?

Comment: I understand that you are learning Erlang, If it is the case, I advice you to use the excellent site from Fred Hebert : [learnYouSomeErlang](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/). The official Erlang documentation is very useful as reference, but not oriented for learning. Good job and have fun!

Comment: This is the same book as https://learnyousomeerlang.com/introduction, and this resource is beautifully put even for a beginner! Thanks a lot for your guidance, I am referring to the same resource, and as I am moving forward, Erlang has started to look quite handy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Erlang has [single assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255632/the-purpose-of-single-assignment/11255741). To use an [example from Armstrong](https://erlang.org/download/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf), in C this works:

```
x = 5;
x = x + 10;
```

But in Erlang it is written:

```
X = 5;
X1 = X + 10;
```